# How can I use a microphone with integrated PA for a level detection purpose?

Tags: comparator, microphone, mems-microphone

I have a [MEMS microphone](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2309010927_LinkMems-LMA2718T421-OA5-2_C7587901.pdf) with an integrated PA. I'm going to use it as a trigger in a low-power device so I wanted to know if that internal PA is enough and I can connect it directly to the  analog comparator of an [ATtiny1626](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwif_7qSz46DAxXr7rsIHSYnBUkQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fww1.microchip.com%2Fdownloads%2FaemDocuments%2Fdocuments%2FMCU08%2FProductDocuments%2FDataSheets%2FATtiny1624-26-27-DataSheet-DS40002234B.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2IzJzgIZhYDKjzDb_eUO6-&opi=89978449). I was going to use it like this:

Here are the specifications of the MEMS microphone:

- Sensitivity: -42 db
- Output impedance: 300 Ohms

The specifications of AC input of the ATtiny1626:

- Input leakage current: 5 nA
- Input offset: 2 +- 20 mV

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdq7Uf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is it possible to use it like this and have a few tens of millivolts to be detected by the AC unit considering enough audio pressure applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *So is it possible to use it like this and have a few tens of millivolts to be detected by the AC unit considering enough audio
> pressure applied?*

The microphone needs to be powered as per this diagram in the [data sheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2309010927_LinkMems-LMA2718T421-OA5-2_C7587901.pdf): -

[image]

So, you need to have a 2 volt nominal DC supply that powers the microphone. But, if you don't mind a small drop in sensitivity you can run the microphone from 1.6 volts to 3.6 volts: -

[image]

Then, making the assumption that the microphone sensitivity is -42 dbV (and not simply -42 dB), we can say that for a sound pressure level of 94 dB at 1 kHz, the microphone RMS output will be 7.94 mV or about 22 mV peak-to-peak.

I can't tell you if this is enough for your needs but, if there's any doubt, you could use a simple op-amp amplifier circuit to boost this by (say) ten times.

Answer (score 1):

The mic has a sensitivity of -42 dB, which more specifically means dB using 1V as reference. So it's similar to electret mics.

-42 dBV is 8 millivolts.

So it's not few tens of millivolts.

At considering what you mean by enough audio pressure applied, you get the 8 millivolts at an ear-deafening level of 94 dB SPL, usually measured with 1 meter distance between mic and the sound source.